# Обработка значения TimeSpan (языка C#) в C++

Tags: c#, c++, время

**Задача:** В приложении, написанном на C#, вводится значение времени в интервале `[00:00:00, 24:00:00)` и заносится в переменную типа `TimeSpan`. Затем это значение должно передаться по сети и правильно прочитаться приложением, написанным на С++.

**Вопрос 1:** В каком виде передавать `TimeSpan`? (У меня оно пока что передается как double TimeSpan.TotalHours).

**Вопрос 2:** Как и с помощью каких средств прочитать это значение на C++?

*P.S.* В языке C++ я чайник.

---

UPD. Еще есть идея передавать отдельно часы минуты и секунды.

Comment: Вообще `TimeSpan` однозначно определяется одним `long`-значением (`Ticks`), можете передавать его. Либо, если это для вас избыточно, просто передавайте целое число секунд

Comment: Первая мысль - передать int-ом (количество секунд в интервале). В рамках 24 часов int-a хватит, даже если вместо секунд передавать миллисекунды

Comment: @АндрейNOP хорошо. А как тогда на стороне приложения C++ преобразовать `long Ticks` в формат `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Общая идея понятна, спасибо

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,108 на плюсах тоже самое сможете написать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавать можно как угодно, главное, чтобы на приёмной стороне можно было восстановить исходное значение. Можно хоть `double`, представляющий кол-во часов, но проще всего это сделать, оперируя целыми `int` (или даже `uint`) числами, так меньше шансов нарваться на какие-то ошибки округления и прочие проблемы несовместимости представлений чисел с плавающей точкой (хотя в большинстве своём всё равно везде опираются на [IEEE-754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)).

Если временной интервал преобразован в целое число, которое соответствует кол-ву секунд (если нужна большая точность, например, миллисекунды, целый тип можно расширить), то после перевода, соблюдения [порядка байт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) и передачи по сети на приёмной (C++) стороне можно написать нечто подобное (в предположении, что число разместили в 32-разрядный `unsigned int`):

```
#include <cstdint>

std::uint32_t sec = 0;

if (sizeof(sec) != recv(sockfd, &sec, sizeof(sec), 0))
{
     // в sec получено кол-во секунд 
}
```

В качестве альтернативного варианта, который будет исключать влияние порядка байт, можно предложить передачу интервала как строки, например `"12:34:56"`. Правда в таком случае размер передаваемых данных возрастёт, однако, принять и передать такую строку будет проще между различными архитектурами, которые могут участвовать в обмене по сете.